# Brexit passport renewal - Will I need to pay again?

Tags: uk, passport-renewals, eu-citizens, brexit

I am a British citizen, and my passport is due to expire in March 2019.

This is about the time I should look to renew it (at a current cost of £75.50), but I've read/heard that when we leave the EU, also destined for March 2019, this will result in passports needing to be replaced with non-EU ones.

Has any advice been published on when/at what cost this replacement will happen?

Some scenarios I've thought about;

1. If I renew now, the new one will stay valid until its expiration; new "British" passports would be issued only as existing "EU" passports expire.
2. I renew now, and in 5 months get issued a new "British" passport, without extra charge.
3. I renew now, and in 5 months my "EU" passport dies, and I have to pay for the new "UK" passport.
4. I don't renew now, and wait for the new "UK" passports to be announced and get one then.

I don't expect the government will have anywhere near the resources in place to handle the millions of new passports required. Are there contingencies in place?

I appreciate there probably isn't an answer to this at the time of asking (as far as I can tell, there are no answers to any of the Brexit problems yet), but perhaps something will become clear in time....

Comment: _"I've read/heard that when we leave the EU, also destined for March 2019 this will result in passports needing to be replaced with non-EU ones"_ Where did you hear this? Please provide sources. I for one heard the opposite from a BBC News article on the subject. Though arguably nobody really knows for sure yet.

Comment: Very relevant [change in rules to carrying over validity from current passport](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/news/2018/09/passport-applicants-hit-out-after-being-given-shorter-than-expec/)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - check your preferred news outlet/google it. One of the brilliant ideas as part of "reclaiming sovereignty" was to have blue, British passports. In true irony, the contract has been given to a Franco-Dutch firm because they are cheaper. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-43807190, https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5533937/Furious-backlash-post-Brexit-passports-overseas.html, https://www.gov.uk/government/news/blue-uk-passport-to-return-after-eu-exit

Comment: @ErosRising I'm aware of that. That has nothing to do with auto-expiring existing documents, regarding which my preferred news outlet said the contrary.

Comment: "I don't expect the government will have anywhere near the resources in place to handle the millions of new passports required": this is yet another point in support of the only reasonable conclusion, which is that existing passports will continue to be valid until they expire.

Comment: There's no reason to replace a passport which states "he majesty requests" ... All changes can be automated because it's only a serial number and a bunch of ID watermarks.

Comment: @ErosRising That just means that newly issued passports will be blue. Even when they went to biometric passports, they didn't invalidate existing passports.

Comment: Get it renewed now while you can still get the red one. Call me an optimist but even if Brexit goes ahead, by the time it expires in 2028, the insanity will be long over and we'll have long since rejoined.

Comment: This is a great question only because the first row of UK passports' cover today reads "European Union", before "United Kingom of Great Britain and Nothern Ireland", making it fully a **European passport**

Comment: Ignoring all the answers for a bit, my question is, why would you want to renew your passport now? I'm pretty sure that when the time comes to renew (some weeks before the expiry date), everyone will have much more info on what will happen exactly than they have now.

Answer (score 84):

The answer is almost certainly #1: it's **extraordinarily unlikely** that existing British passports would be completely invalidated by Brexit.  A British passport states that you're a British citizen, which will continue to be the case even if Britain leaves the EU.

While I can't point to any official sources, I can note that a) passports of European countries issued before they joined the EU remained valid even without the EU designation, and b) passports of countries that ceased to exist, such as the Soviet Union, still remained valid afterwards.  (It took Russia six years after the dissolution of the USSR to even start issuing Russian passports!)

Comment: This is the only thing that makes sense. When the UK leaves the EU, its citizens will no longer be part of the EU either, no matter what's stamped on the front cover of existing passports.

Comment: @MikeHarris, it may turn out to be more complicated than that if the [Amsterdam case](http://europeanlawblog.eu/2018/02/19/does-member-state-withdrawal-from-the-european-union-extinguish-eu-citizenship-c13640244-kg-za-17-1327-rechtbank-amsterdam-the-amsterdam-case/) is revived.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I don't think so. The Amsterdam case revolves around the notion of EU citizenship. Citizenship and passport possession are not that directly linked. In particular, EU citizenship is not at all linked to EU-stylized passports.

Comment: @MSalters, I specifically addressed Mike Harris' comment, not the answer. I assume you're not saying that EU citizenship is unrelated to the question of whether "*[UK] citizens will no longer be part of the EU*", so I don't think we're actually in disagreement.

Comment: If there is no deal I wouldn't be confident that UK passports which mention the EU would be valid.

Comment: @user can you point to any credible source that supports your suspicion?  It doesn't make any sense unless things get extremely ugly, and even then the EU cannot invalidate British passports that mention the EU; it could only refuse to accept them.  For such passports to be invalidated in other countries, the EU would have to convince them also not to accept them.  I don't imagine that things would get that ugly; it wouldn't be in the EU's interests.

Comment: @MSalters correct. It revolves around people with UK citizenship demanding they be granted Dutch citizenship in case Brexit would trigger them losing their EU citizenship (which seems logical to me, why would UK citizens be EU citizens when the UK is not part of the EU, but I'm too simple minded to be a lawyer or politician apparently).

Comment: @phoog No one can be certain, but I wouldn't chance it. The EU may feel that there are issues with the passports, e.g. EU citizens can now use the consulates of other EU nations in emergency situations but that right won't extend to ex-citizens post brexit. At the very least it could cause some confusion. It will probably be fine, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @user you "wouldn't chance it"?  Meaning what?  You could plan to apply a non-EU UK passport on Brexit day, but you should check the news first, because by the time the post office opens it should already be clear whether the EU is admitting people with UK passports that do say "European Union" on them.  And, as I said, the EU has no control over whether other countries accept those passports.

Comment: @user: A UK passport is just a UK passport. Mention of Europe on it won't mean that EU countries are compelled to accept you. It just confirms you are a UK citizen and will be treated as appropriate to an EU citizen. The reason that we can move around europe more easily now isn't because our passport says so but because of the EU agreements that say so. After Brexit then it will be whatever agreements (or lack of) that determine how we enter EU countries, not the word europe on our passport.

Answer (score 31):

In your [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123686/brexit-passport-renewal-will-i-need-to-pay-again#comment305214_123686), you linked to an [official source](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/blue-uk-passport-to-return-after-eu-exit) that (rather understatedly) answers your question:

> To save the taxpayer money, the newly designed passports will be introduced in a phased approach.
>
> After the UK leaves the EU, burgundy passports will continue to be issued but with no reference to the European Union.
>
> New blue and gold passports will be issued from October 2019, when the new passport contract begins, to those renewing or applying for a new passport.
>
> **There is no need for British passport holders to do anything ahead of their current passport renewal date.**

(Emphasis added.)

Of course, the first paragraph is somewhat disingenuous:

> After Brexit, the UK travel document will no longer be required to conform to EU standards. So in a move to symbolise our national identity, the cover will be changing from the standard EU burgundy colour to a blue and gold design.

This implies falsely that the burgundy cover was required by EU standards; in fact, it is just a suggestion, and the UK could have gone back to a previous passport color, or indeed any passport color, without leaving the EU, just as Croatia has [retained](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/blue-passports-brexit-colour-change-leave-eu-withdrawal-european-union-countries-travel-a8124526.html) blue passports [after joining it](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2017/dec/22/blue-passports-taking-back-control-imposed-league-of-nations-burgundy-passport-eu).

The implications for your question:

> I've read/heard that when we leave the EU, also destined for March 2019, this will result in passports needing to be replaced with non-EU ones.

That is incorrect.  Existing passports will remain valid until they expire.

> Has any advice been published on when/at what cost this replacement will happen?

No, because there will be no such required replacement.  People who want to pay the fee to renew their passports early will presumably be able to do that.

> Some scenarios I've thought about;
>   1. If I renew now, the new one will stay valid until its expiration; new "British" passports would be issued only as existing "EU" passports expire.

This is what will happen.

> 2. I renew now, and in 5 months get issued a new "British" passport, without extra charge.

That is wishful thinking, but fortunately it won't be necessary to get a new passport.

> 3. I renew now, and in 5 months my "EU" passport dies, and I have to pay for the new "UK" passport.

No.  The EU doesn't issue passports.  An "EU passport" is a national passport issued to an EU citizen by an EU member state.  When the UK ceases to be an EU member state, UK passports issued to British citizens will cease to be EU passports, notwithstanding any references they may contain to the European Union.  But they will continue to be UK passports, and valid.

> 4. I don't renew now, and wait for the new "UK" passports to be announced and get one then.

They've already been announced, as noted above, but you can certainly wait until October 2019 before getting your new passport, if your travel plans allow.  In determining whether your travel plans allow, don't forget that some countries require extra validity beyond the end of your visit.

Comment: The UK could not have "*gone back to blue passports*" because it never had them. They used to be black.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - have a read of this [Home Office blog](https://homeofficemedia.blog.gov.uk/2017/12/30/rebuttal-times-article-on-colour-of-new-passport/). An extract: `Since its introduction in 1921, there have been a few variants of that navy blue colour but it has never been black, as some commentators have suggested.` It's a common misconception that British passports were ever black - occasionally they were _very_ dark blue, but never black.

Comment: Well, they were so dark in colour as to be indistinguishable from black to many people. The one I have at the back of a drawer somewhere certainly is.

Comment: Oh god, it's [that dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress) all over again...

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed.  I express no opinion on the appropriate name for the color of any passport.  I will edit the answer to reflect that.  Maybe I should denote the Croatian passports as [*plave*](https://hr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plava).

Comment: @PeterTaylor is it better now?

Comment: "*very* dark blue" - reminds  me of Father Ted

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need it soon, leave it until it's about to expire. This is because the government have recently changed the rules and no longer add the additional time to the expiry - so if you applied now (October 2018), your new passport will expire in October 2028, not March 2029 as it would have under the old rules.

They've done this because the Schengen rules require passports from third countries to have been issued within the last 10 years, and if you've got a passport valid for 10 years and 9 months (as was possible under the old system), you'd not be able to use it to visit Schengen for the last 9 months.

See [this gov.uk page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/travelling-to-the-eu-with-a-uk-passport-if-theres-no-brexit-deal/travelling-to-the-eu-with-a-uk-passport-if-theres-no-brexit-deal) for more details:

> Since 2001, some adult British passports were issued with a validity longer than 10 years. This is because if you renewed your passport before it expired you were allowed to have the time left on your old passport added to your new passport. The maximum validity period possible was 10 years and 9 months. This means you can’t use the expiry date to check if your adult passport will be valid under the new rules.
>
> From the beginning of September 2018 extra validity is no longer added to passports and the maximum validity for a new adult UK passport will be 10 years, and for a child passport will be 5 years. We have made this change to follow recommendations set out by the International Civil Aviation Organisation and to help provide clarity about passport validity in the Schengen area in the future.

Comment: That would be immensely stupid. With a passport valid for 10 years 9 months you will be able to visit Europe for exactly 10 years. With a passport valid for ten years you can only visit for 9 years and 6 months. The rules are: Passport not older than ten years, and passport valid for another 6 months. So you want a passport valid for 10 years 6 months to use it for ten years.

Answer (score 7):

What's more of an issue is the possibilty of needing some number of months' validity for visits to Europe in the future (unlike now).  Many countries require 6 months from date of entry, or something similar.  This applies in particular [to the EU](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/passport-rules-for-travel-to-europe-after-brexit) (gov.uk).  This doesn't affect you directly as your passport runs out almost exactly on brexit day. the rule does mean that a surge in passport applications can be expected, starting imminently.  This is likely to mean increased lead times around the time you need to renew yours.

Comment: While this is true, it does not answer the question.  The actual requirement in the Schengen area (and the rest of the EU, I believe, except perhaps Ireland) is that passports be valid at least three months beyond the anticipated date of departure.  Since an arriving visitor may stay no longer than 90 days at once, and sometimes less, this is often incorrectly stated as requiring six months of validity beyond the date of arrival.

Comment: @phoog between my "something like" and the "should have 6 months" the UK government say, I think its close enough. After all, I lead with "some number" But the more important part of the answer is the increased lead time which we can expect. For obvious reasons official sources are thin on the ground for that

Comment: Yes, my comment was somewhat unclear.  The first sentence isn't particularly related to the rest of the comment, which was just trying to add some precision to the information you presented in support of your point.  The first sentence is just saying that the answer doesn't address the question of whether pre-Brexit passports will be valid after Brexit.  I do agree that it is significant that processing times may increase, and that this partly addresses the question, so I have upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I renewed my British passport just a few weeks ago using the online service. A few days later, my new burgundy passport arrived with an expiry date in Sept 2028. I have no doubt that it will remain valid for all travel even after 29 March 2019.

The only change that I am aware of, is sometime after Brexit the UK passport office intends to start issuing passports with a blue cover instead of the current burgundy colour.

Comment: Surely the inside of the passport will change as well as the cover, since all the EU-specific stuff will be removed.

Comment: References to "European Union" on the cover and page 1 will surely go, but all the other translated material may well remain as useful. It will be interesting to see exactly what is removed.

Comment: @AndrewLeach my passport doesnt say European Union on it... All the graphics on the front cover of mine have worn off!

Comment: There isn't anything on the inside which is EU-specific. You might be thinking of the ICAO specifications, which cover things like the translations of labels, machine readable segment, biometrics etc.

Comment: @jacksonj04 there's no page with the data elements translated into the EU official languages?

Comment: @phoog The personal details page should have the details in at least one of English, French or Spanish, but that's a result of ICAO rules (https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p3_cons_en.pdf) and nothing to do with the EU.

Comment: @jacksonj04 actually, since the main language of the passport is one of those three, the personal data page should have at least two of them.  But I'm not talking about the personal data page itself, but about the key that identifies the data elements in *every* official EU language on a separate page.  That page is the reason for the parenthetical numbers visible in [wikipedia's image of the personal data page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:British_passport_data_page.jpg).  It would of course be impractical to include all those languages on the data page itself.

Comment: Pre-EU passports included a French translation, but only that.

Answer (score 4):

Mine was due to run out on March 2020, I went to the post office a week ago and paid £90.40 for the renewal, it arrived yesterday 30th October 2019, the words European Union had gone but it was still in Burgandy not Blue, they’re using old stock until the beginning of the year.

Comment: Yes, since April these passports (without EU) have been issued, while the other stock is being used up. There have been **no reports** that EU Citizens rights have been denied due to the lack of EU on the passport. https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-47833702

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here consider this topic from an entirely UK-centric view. For its main use, it is relatively irrelevant whether British authorities consider a UK passport with "European Union" on the cover valid or not.

Where you need a passport is entry and exit to another country. It is very unlikely, but you could easily argue EU countries would consider the "European Union" cover as untrue and thus deny passport validity (There have been lots of similar examples in the past). How this will be handled in future is not a simple UK decision, but rather would be one small part of the EU/UK series of treaties that need to be sorted out between the UK and the EU.

Comment: *There have been lots of similar examples in the past* - can you link to any of these?

Comment: @nekomatic Most recent in Europe maybe Greece not accepting passports of the former Yugoslavian Republic of Macedonia until recently (*A  special  procedure  will  apply  at  the  border  with Greece. The Greek authorities will not put entry or exit stamps  in  passports  issued  by  the  former  Yugoslav 
Republic of Macedonia. Instead, the Greek authorities will proceed by stamping a separate sheet that will be given to the traveller.* (From an EU information sheet of 2009)

Comment: Other example: A *Northern Cypriot Passport* will allow you entry into only 5 countries (Turkey, USA and Pakistan amongst them) and nowhere else. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cypriot_passport

Comment: In the Macedonia case that was in protest at the use of the disputed name 'Macedonia', I assume? OK, fair point, but I think it's *extremely* unlikely to be replicated in the case of the UK - ***if*** Brexit goes ahead, nobody is likely to think that the UK is wrongly laying claim to being an EU member because they haven't cancelled pre-Brexit passports. In the Northern Cyprus case this is because most countries *don't actually recognise Northern Cyprus*.

Comment: @nekomatic Yes, the Macedonia example is maybe the better one - Greece was forced to accept the passport by EU regulations, but didn't like the name on it, so told their administration "don't stamp that thing". My point is not so much the likeliness or non-likeliness of such denials, but rather that it's not the UK administration alone who decides passport validity. EU could very well state "you had two years..." - And I did mention "very unlikely" for a purpose.

Comment: @tofro I don't see the relevance of Northern Cyprus. Most countries don't accept Northern Cypriot passports simply because they don't recognize Northern Cyprus as being a country.

Comment: @DavidRicherby From a purely legal viewpoint, with no bi-lateral agreements between the EU and UK which is still a threat, there is no immigration policy at all the EU/UK relationships could fall back to. This would effectively end up in the same situation from a travel POV.

Comment: @tofro The lack of an immigration policy would require British citizens to get visas to visit the EU and vice-versa. There is no danger that the EU will stop recognizing the UK as a country, so no such grounds on which the EU would stop recognizing British passports as being passports.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Again from a POV that takes only the raw legal situation after hard Brexit into account: No. In order to request, administer and grant visa (on both ends) there must be fundamental agreements in place. There is nothing you can fall back to (not even the pre-EU situation, as all EU countries have delegated immigration jurisdiction to the EU, so anything pre-EU is void). I'm not saying the EU will stop recognizing UK as a country. But it will need to stop recognizing the UK as a country it has an immigration agreement with (which has the same net effect on the passport).

Comment: I would like to point out that countries are free to interpret the rules as they wish. There is no guarantee that a pre brexit passport will work. But also no guaratee a bost brexit passport will either.

Answer (score 0):

Current passports will stay valid for ten years after they are issued. The only difference: With current rules, if your passport expired March 2019 and you renewed in January 2019, you received a passport valid to March 2029. Now it will only be valid for ten years, that is January 2029.

What you need to decide is whether you want an old passport for the next ten years, or if you want to stand out in every passport queue as a Little Englander with then "new" (1970's style) blue passport. If you want to get the old passport, renew before March 2019. If you want the new passport, renew after March 2019. This may mean that you are without a passport for a short time, or if you have a brand-new old style passport and want a new-style one then you'd have to pay.

Comment: The new passports won't be "1970s style"; they'll only be blue.  In every other respect, especially size and shape, they'll resemble the current passport.